# What is the missing digit in this 3x5 table?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a sequence of numbers ordered in a tabular
> form. Find the next term labeled x.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Transcription:
4, 3, 2, 5, 6
5, 6, 9, 2, 4
11, 9, 7, x, 14

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

1. 11
2. 9
3. 3
4. 5
5. 8

This peculiar problem I found it in my puzzles book *Reason and Logic* from 2000's. From the looks of it seems to be an adaptation of the riddles featured in a reprinted copy of Martin Gardner's 50's book of Recreational puzzles.

On reading my book there is a part where it mentions that there isn't really a specific method to solve this. However by looking some solved puzzles it seems that the author intends that a pattern will emerge if you look at the columns in the arrangement.

I attempted to do this and it worked but for some:

Let's say the first column it could be:

4 x 2 + 3 = 11

3 x 2 + 3 = 9

2 x 2 + 3 = 7

But it failed in the fifth column as 6 x 2 + 3 ≠ 14

Another suggestion given in the book was to label the columns in the arrangement 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and then use these numbers to match the numbers in the third row. I attempted different combinations using squared those digits, sums and differences and still nothing.

I already attempted to look into the OEIS but it didn't helped much.

Can someone help me with this puzzle? Is there a pattern, or something else which I haven't noticed, that could be used to logically find the answer? **Please try to be the most detailed as possible in your answer and include a step by step explanation as I feel lost in this one.**

Answer (score 3):

Note that [I'm generally against this kind of questions on Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7064/71652). I'm just posting this answer because I randomly realized the pattern. Really, there's no way to write down a step by step explanation on a pattern-finding question, and there's no general way to solve this category of problems. If you really ask me to write how to approach this problem, maybe I can, but it only applies to *this problem*, and you won't be able to solve something else by applying it.

The answer looks like this:

> On each column, let the first number $x$ and the second number $y$. Then the third number is $xy - x - y$. So the number to be placed at the question mark is $10 - 5 - 2 = 3$, which is choice 3.

Comment: Yes I read your entry in the link which you mentioned. But I didn't knew it beforehand. Again, it makes me to believe that such sort of problems in spotting patterns seems to require patience. Probably I would had realized it if I had considered multiplying the digits in the columns. Since I found this problem in a section related with series and patterns I thought that due its nature maybe there was something different as with just a regular series of numbers. From the problems I've seen I think that in **these sorts of problems** as you indicated will only work this approach.

Comment: In this particular problem or problems similar to this, it seems that a way to spot a pattern is to focus in the columns and not jump to the next. But should it be considered a norm?. As I mentioned I tried adding the digits, squaring them, multiplying them by some digit and then a difference and nothing work. From then on I thought, **what else can I do?** In desperation some ideas came to my mind, would it be a square root of something, or a cubic root, or a logarithm?. But does it really require going that far?. Maybe can you include in your answer what you thought first?

Comment: I know it would apply only to this problem, but such explanation would help me to see if it could be extended in similar scenarios. Can you help me by including maybe a short guidelines on what sort of operations should someone try to look for first instead of attempting other things which wouldn't yield any results?

Answer (score 1):

I did find a pattern that works for the columns:

> (A * B) - (A + B)
>  eg:
>  (4 * 5) - (4 + 5) = 20 - 9 = 11

This means X is:

> (5 * 2) - (5 + 2) = 10 - 7 = 3

As for how I found this:

> I did guess the pattern for this one.
>  It helps to keep certain numbers in mind while figuring it out.
>  What I mean is:
>  I kept the sum and multiplication in mind while trying to see a pattern.
>  Going from 4, 5 to 11 isn't easy in itself,
>  but going from 20, 9 to 11 is trivial.
>  Most of the times some guessing is neccesary.

Comment: I understand that this requires guessing and patience. But I didn't understood your commentary about going from 20, 9 to 11 to be trivial. Did you meant $11+9=20$? There are other sorts of operations that someone can try, what other choices did you attempted? I previously commented that I had confusion on whether to attempt to search for squared or cubes or even logarithms, but would it require that level of sophistication?. Did these choices came to your mind when trying to spot the pattern?.

Comment: What I meant is, if you see 20 , 9 and 11 it is easier to see a connection than when you see 4, 5 and 11. (ie 20 - 9 = 11) . As for other choices, I didn't even need to think about them in this case. If the method is simple enough, it's most likely the intended answer for these riddles. This only explains how I found the answer to this one. Since you don't know what the creator was thinking this method is only limited to some riddles. There is no single method for figuring out these riddles, people can always come up with something new.

Comment: Here are some operations I often try as well (in series, but you could look at columns and rows separatly for this).
I look at the problem by keeping sums, multiplications, squares... in mind (as in my answer).
I try looking at differences between the numbers. (eg 1 2 4 7 11 ?. Here the difference is always one higher and the next one would be 16).
I try comparing the series (or even the series of the differences) to known series/special numbers. (could be linked to primes for example)
I try some non-mathematical things (eg counting the number of holes in the numbers).

Comment: But people on puzzling SE don't really like these questions because the answer is opinionbased. Only the creator of the riddle can really know 'the' answer, and there is no fixed way to know which answer is really the best.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't know that such criteria on puzzling SE. But it seems logical because as you mentioned in these questions only the author knows the answer. However, I doubt that this should enough reason for not trying to solve the puzzle its as eliminating all pattern puzzles altogether. Anyways, the source of my confusion is exactly how to tackle these questions. You mentioned that one diagnostic was to look for primes, series, operations, you even mentioned squares.

Comment: Again the source of the initial comment from above was if there was a rule of thumb on where to look first before digging into the big guns?. Let's say, cubes, squares, logarithms, or even other sophisticated functions, like inverse or something. I understand due the nature of these problems it could be anything. But what do you recommend to try first?.

Comment: There really isn't any rule of thumb, but I would try to check whatever seems easiest to check. The way to solve the actual puzzles depends on the creator, and that's where the guessing comes in.
No matter how 'good' you are in these puzzles, there will always be some way that you didn't think of.
The operations I listed above are in the order I would usually try to solve such puzzles, but maybe you will be able to solve most riddles faster by trying something else first. Like I said, it depends on what the creator of the riddle came up with.